# AVPlayerLayer Vs AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, avplayer

I am new to iOS app developing field. I am trying to capture video using **AVFoundation**. I am successful in this. But when I tried to play the  video back using **MPMoviePlayerController**, I got too many issues. So I am trying to play using **AVPlayer**.
But in **AVPlayer** there are two approaches **AVPlayerLayer** and **AVPlayerViewController**.
I tried searching about those, but I didn't get any particular reason to choose one.
Can anyone suggest me which is better to use?

Comment: AVPlayerLayer and AVPlayerViewController are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AVPlayerViewController` is an all in one solution. You setup your `AVPlayer` with a video and present the player controller. It handles all the playing and has its own controls baked in (I'm sure you've used seen this in other apps). It is the simplest way to show a video.

`AVPlayerLayer` is for when you want to add some customization, like adding  your own controls or extra views, or not making the video full screen.

Comment: Can I use AVPlayerViewController with fewer controls?

Comment: I know you can turn off some of the controls, but I don't know to what extent. Check out the [AVPlayerViewController docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller).

Comment: @keithbhunter For statement, AVPlayerViewController  handles all the playing and has its own controls baked in. Can we remove it and add custom controls ?